# Migration of custom farm solution from SharePoint 2010 to SharePOint 2016 or 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

As the support for SharePoint 2010 is ending, we are in a need to migrate custom farm solution (.wsp) from SP 2010 to SP 2016 or 2019. Can anyone let me know the things we need to consider before making such a change?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the farm solutions to support 2013 with v14.5 and v15 modes. This will help transition the sites from a v14.5 (SharePoint 2010) to v15 (SharePoint 2013+).

Reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/upgrade-sharepoint-2010-farm-solution-to-sharepoint-2013/

Farm solutions of SharePoint 2013 support using in SharePoint 2016, in many cases you will not have to make any changes to your farm solution.

Reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a3dc08c-ccea-4cb9-a469-4d0786295758/how-to-upgrade-sharepoint-2013-custom-solutions-to-sharepoint-2016?forum=sharepointdevelopment